# how to share the some pods in two target by podfile

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoapods, xctest

```
xcodeproj 'Demo.xcodeproj'

platform :ios, "6.0"

target "Demo" do
    pod 'Demo-A', '3.1.1'
    pod 'Demo-B', '1.0'
    pod 'Demo-C', '~> 1.9.0'
    pod 'Demo-D', '~> 1.1'

    pod 'AA', '0.0.1'
    pod 'BB', '0.0.1'
    pod 'CC', '0.0.1'
    pod 'DD', '0.0.1'
    pod 'EE', '0.0.1'
    pod 'FF', '0.0.1'
    pod 'GG', '0.0.1'
end

target "DemoTests" do
    pod 'DemoTests-X', '3.1.1'
    pod 'DemoTests-Y', '0.4.0'
    pod 'DemoTests-Z', '4.1.1'

    pod 'AA', '0.0.1'
    pod 'BB', '0.0.1'
    pod 'CC', '0.0.1'
    pod 'DD', '0.0.1'
    pod 'EE', '0.0.1'
    pod 'FF', '0.0.1'
    pod 'GG', '0.0.1'
end

target "DemoWidget" do
    pod 'DemoWidget-1', '3.1.1'
    pod 'DemoWidget-2', '0.4.0'
    pod 'DemoWidget-3', '4.1.1'
end
```

this is my podfile . as u can see.

```
pod 'AA', '0.0.1'
pod 'BB', '0.0.1'
pod 'CC', '0.0.1'
pod 'DD', '0.0.1'
pod 'EE', '0.0.1'
pod 'FF', '0.0.1'
pod 'GG', '0.0.1'
```

this code is appear twice.  DemoTests is test target for Demo target.while i write test file and improt the source file in Demo target.it will dependence some file in pods which in Demo target,but not in DemoTests target. so i write this Podfile code twice for dependence.
but,it's ugly! my colleagues and i have to maintain two sets of such code.and my Podfile will be Bloated！
i want to maintain this code once! how to do it~
I love cocoapods! i believe it will solve my problem ~
waiting for  u answer~~~~

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use it like this to reduce your length of podfile and would also be able to maintain code once!!!

```
xcodeproj 'Demo.xcodeproj'

platform :ios, "6.0"

def common_pods_for_target
    pod 'AA', '0.0.1'
    pod 'BB', '0.0.1'
    pod 'CC', '0.0.1'
    pod 'DD', '0.0.1'
    pod 'EE', '0.0.1'
    pod 'FF', '0.0.1'
    pod 'GG', '0.0.1'
end

target "Demo" do
    pod 'Demo-A', '3.1.1'
    pod 'Demo-B', '1.0'
    pod 'Demo-C', '~> 1.9.0'
    pod 'Demo-D', '~> 1.1'
    common_pods_for_target
end

target "DemoTests" do
    pod 'DemoTests-X', '3.1.1'
    pod 'DemoTests-Y', '0.4.0'
    pod 'DemoTests-Z', '4.1.1'
    common_pods_for_target
end

target "DemoWidget" do
    pod 'DemoWidget-1', '3.1.1'
    pod 'DemoWidget-2', '0.4.0'
    pod 'DemoWidget-3', '4.1.1'
end
```

Just define all your common pods in a variable and use it in the targets you want.

Comment: Notice, that apparently you should use lowercase for the first letter.

Answer (score 12):

CocoaPods now [recommends using an `abstract_target`](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html) if you want multiple targets to share the same pods. Notice how the actual targets are nested under the new abstract one.

```
# There are no targets called "Shows" in any Xcode projects
abstract_target 'Shows' do
  pod 'ShowsKit'
  pod 'Fabric'

  # Has its own copy of ShowsKit + ShowWebAuth
  target 'ShowsiOS' do
    pod 'ShowWebAuth'
  end

  # Has its own copy of ShowsKit + ShowTVAuth
  target 'ShowsTV' do
    pod 'ShowTVAuth'
  end
end
```

Comment: Is `Shows` one of the targets name? So there are three targets, `Shows`, `ShowsiOS` and `ShowsTV`

Comment: @malhobayyeb only two targets, `ShowsiOS` and `ShowsTV`. The `Shows` "target" is abstract - it doesn't actually exist.

Comment: It creates 2 copies of ShowsKit. Is there a way to have a single copy?